# Window glitches and lagging problems in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bug-reporting

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 for some development needs and I often encounter with lagging issues and glitches as shown below: (see in the titlebar and icons and in the eclipse in the background)

[image]

I've no idea what it's all about. Can you suggest me what can I do?

Comment: What is your video card and driver?

Comment: Are you using a Nvidia Optimus system? Could you please take a screenshot of the Monitors section of System Settings?

Comment: BTW, I do not have any additional graphics card. I use a laptop with Intel mobile GMA.

Comment: What laptop are you using exactly?

Comment: @nastys Toshiba L510

Comment: @Gowtham Please look in `Displays` from the Control Center if there are two monitors.

Comment: @nastys no only one.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU isn't completely supported. You can use a workaround or disable the GPU driver and use the CPU for rendering.

**Workaround**

Install the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/).

Open it, then go to `Composite`
[image]

Set as follows (change the refresh rate according to your monitor if needed):
[image]

Go back and go to `OpenGL`
[image]

Set as follows:
[image]

**Disable the Intel GMA GPU**

Open a terminal and enter:

```
`sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel`
```

Comment: This seems to be bite my warranty. Are you sure I want to try these?

Comment: @Gowtham The first part (workaround) should not cause problems because we're only disabling some features of the window manager (and will certainly not damage the GPU). The second uninstalls the driver, and you can reinstall it later if you have any problem. Both will not void your warranty.
I think you should experiment with options in CCSM first, then remove the driver if it doesn't work.

Comment: Your workaround almost crashed my system.

Comment: @Gowtham Don't worry, it is normal that when you check or uncheck some options the display acts a bit strange for some seconds (I forgot to say).

Comment: This is what happened before entering the remove command. [http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1OvJ.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V1OvJ.png) and I tried to reset all the changes, but that too failed and removed all the top bar and launcher. Finally I reset it using `unity-tweak-tool --reset-all`

Comment: @Gowtham It's because you disabled "Vertex buffer object". Please try again without disabling that.

Comment: @Gowtham I tested this personally and it works fine. Only `Vertex buffer object` was wrong (sorry).
http://i.imgur.com/mF9YfcN.png